# Performance Testing: What does fluctuating Response time indicates?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, response-time

Below is the graph which I received after the performance test execution.
I am confused about the fluctuated response time graph.
NOTE: 1) Throughput graph is also fluctuating. 2) I did not receive any error during test.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It normally indicates that either application under test or JMeter engine is overloaded hence it cannot handle/produce stable load pattern.

Your response time is around 1.5 minutes which seems little bit high to me so I would suggest that you need to monitor the application under test and check:

- whether it has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network IO, etc. as it might be the case the application is short on RAM and [goes swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) and disk IO is much slower than RAM, it can be checked using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
- whether it is [properly configured for high loads](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/appservers.shtml) as its middleware (database, application server, load balancer, etc. need to be tuned, spike-like response time pattern may stand for intensive GC activity
- in any case ensure that [JMeter is also properly configured for high load](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and isn't short on resources as if JMeter isn't able to send/receive requests fast enough you will get false-negative results

Single chart never tells the full story, you need to correlate information from all the possible sources, collect log files, etc.

  -

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable help! Your detailed explanation helped me a lot in understanding. I will definitely look into other sources as well. :)